# Is there a way to get a list of props used within a component without reading documentation or code?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

Say I want to know the defined props for an arbitrary component.  For this example, we'll say it's a Button from Material UI.  I can go read the documentation and find the available props, but is there some method/value I can use in a parent component to find what props a potential child component might care about?  I feel like there should be a way.  If they are my own components, I can export any prop types I have defined, but I'm looking more for a solution for third-party components that I don't know the props for.  Any ideas or reference material is much appreciated.

Comment: @types/material-ui

Comment: @gumingfeng, thanks for the reference, but I'm not looking for a solution to just Material UI components, I'm asking if there is a more general approach for an arbitrary component